# Saving against secondary effects of poison

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, poison

If a character is successful in a saving throw against poison do they have to roll to save against the secondary effect?

Comment: Hi Mouse, and welcome to the site. Please check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and note we're a Q&A site and don't work like a forum. I've revised your question to just be straightforward -- we work best when solving specific problems, and we don't handle questions that just generically ask for arbitrary tips. If you want to seek arbitrary discussion or tips, [please ask a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), since they're better suited to doing that.

Answer (score 6):

There are two meanings of "Poison" in 5e. Poison is a type of damage and a condition. What saving throws are required and what effects those saving throws have are detailed in the description of the attack or effect that causes poison damage or the poison condition. For example, the Druid cantrip Poison Spray requires a Constitution saving throw to avoid taking damage. If you pass the save, there is no damage. Fail and you'll suffer the 1d12 poison damage from the spell, but no poison condition.

Typically, attacks that apply the poison condition (e.g. from monsters) will specify a duration for the effect. The poison condition will last until that duration ends or if it is cured (by Lesser Restoration for example). There is no other saving throw to break out of the condition unless it is specified in the description of the attack that causes poison.

Comment: Not to split hairs but the condition is "Poisoned" with is applied by the use of "Poison".